# Xamarin.Forms embed native controls for WPF

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

Following [Native Views in XAML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/native-views/xaml) I see that it is possible to embed native views in XAML by specifying a value for targetPlatform in an appropriate xmlns attribute value.

In my sample project I have confirmed this works for UWP by using targetPlatform=Windows. This actually works fine.

However I wish to do the same thing for a WPF control and was wondering which targetPlatform value to use. I see from the article that targetPlatform should be set to one of values of the TargetPlatform enumeration. Looking at the documentation for [TargetPlatform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.targetplatform?view=xamarin-forms) enumeration I see that it is obsolete and does not have a value for WPF. (I tried to use Other but this does not work.)

I see that [Device.RuntimePlatform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.device?view=xamarin-forms) may be used in code, but not sure if there is a way to use it with the xmlns attribute.

How do I conditionally embed WPF native views in XAML? If this is not possible, what's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

At the moment WPF support is in beta and it is not possible, as you can see it is on TODO list at the moment: https://github.com/mohachouch/forms-wpf-progress/blob/master/Status.md

You can port any view using the custom renderer, but adding and binding properties even for just one control is a huge work.